# How to parse JSON Array in android?

Tags: android

I have a JSON Array as follows:

jSONArray: `{"li":[["apple\r\n","orange\r\n","mango\r\n"]]}`

I want only the list as [apple, orange, mango] in android. Can anybody explain how to parse it in android without \r\n. I have tried as follows:

```
JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray(results.toString());  // which is the JSON Array
                    for(int i=0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();
                        JSONObject issue = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                        String _pubKey = issue.getString("li");
                        }
```

So, I am getting pubKey as  [["apple\r\n","orange\r\n","mango\r\n"]]. I dont want \r\n.

Comment: do you have search on google ? what difficulties you have face?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace those characters while parsing.

Example: If *fruit* is the string you want to put in your JSONArray *jsonArray*, call:

```
jsonArray.put(fruit.trim().replace("\r", "").replace("\n", ""));
```